# preserving identity specification values when exporting between sql server db's (sql2005/8)

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have a webhost with a SQL server DB and want to move my DB to their facility.  I don't have access to use restore/backup, but had success using the 'export' function.  In that, I specified the source and destination DB instances, and it all moved without difficulty.

However now I've migrated the site, the first attempt to write a row to a table gives this error:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'eventID', table   'advanced_PT.dbo.tblEvents';     
column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
  The statement has been terminated.
```

When I look in the DB, the first column (eventID) is populated with its values, but identity specification is off.  Trying to turn it on makes it want to recreate the table which is no good, as it already has data.

Is there a way to export and preserve this?  I found a link to SET_IDENTITY_INSERT but it doesn't look like the trick.

(my version of ent manager is 2008, the host has 2005)

Thanks!

Mark

Comment: if you want to preserve IDENTITY values then you need to use SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON

Comment: The issue would have been with the original `create table` statement. Annoyingly the identity property can not be changed on a column after the table is created. The only way of changing a column to be an identity column is either to add a new column and drop the existing one (necessitating an update to every row in the table, wasting space from the dropped column and changing the column order) or to completely rebuild the table. This seems pretty ridiculous to me as the only change necessary is to update some metadata somewhere!

Comment: THanks Martin.  Not sure what I would have done wrong in creating it, I didn't use a script based 'create table' command.  Rather I just used the enterprise mgr gui to create a new table, then went down to the properties and said 'Identity specification = yes' etc.  So it was an identity column from the moment it was first created, I think.  I agree though, it's only a metadata change, it seems like an unnecessary amount of punishment :)

Comment: After messing around with the DAC and single user mode I think I figured out the exact metadata change needed with the `idtval` and `status` columns in `sys.syscolpars`. I wouldn't try this on anything but a test database though!

Comment: That metadata change sounds a long way out of my depth!  Thanks for looking into it Martin.  Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to close this off, after various trial and error I found the best method seems to be:

Right click DB -> Tasks->Generate scripts

In 'set scripting options'

- say generate to new query window (I guess if it gets big it needs to go to a file)
- Click advanced button and change the following from their defaults (doesn't save these preferences, annoyingly)

  - Generate script for Dependent objects: true
  - Include if NOT EXISTS: true (I believe this just basically puts an 'if' so if it tries to drop a table that isn't there yet, no errors result)
  - Include system constraint names: True (I think)
  - Script DROP and CREATE - depends if the DB exists.  If you say create I think it might actually try to create the DB itself, not just the tables, so if you've created the DB in plesk it can be best to use the IF NOT EXISTS thing and say 'DROP and CREATE' in this box.
  - Script for Server version: change this if needed
  - Types of data to script: VERY IMPORTANT - say 'Schema and Data' otherwise you just get blank tables
  - Script Indexes /Script Full Text indexes: TRUE - if you don't do this the identity specification is lost

Then, the script will appear in your query window.  Go to the destination DB, right click, say 'new query', paste this in and execute.

It may be if data gets big, that its best to create 'schema only' with the above, then move the data itself using the import/export wizards.  Haven't tried this though.

Hope that is helpful to others... :)  If anyone has a better way please message me!